# CoreData to-many-relationship pretends not to be containing an object which is inserted in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I've a very strange issue. This happens occasionally when I'm trying to remove an object from a to many relationship.

We have 2 objects, a `DriverRoute` which contains multiple `DriverRouteDelivery`objects. I try to remove one of the `DriverRouteDelivery`objects from the `DriverRoute`, but sometimes the item can't be found in the set even though it's there. I `po`ed the output.

```
<DriverRoute: 0x812041a0> (entity: DriverRoute; id: 0x7c0ed070 <x-coredata://E8AAE873-94B7-42F4-A39A-3A8D7C567747/DriverRoute/p8> ; data: {
    changed = "2015-06-22 15:56:28 +0000";
    createdTimestamp = "2015-06-22 15:36:25 +0000";
    driver = "0x7f52f080 <x-coredata://E8AAE873-94B7-42F4-A39A-3A8D7C567747/Driver/p1>";
    id = "4CFA3568-B95E-46D8-A9C7-5EC44BF1ADA8";
    returnRoute = "0x7bf15e70 <x-coredata://E8AAE873-94B7-42F4-A39A-3A8D7C567747/Route/p23>";
    routeDeliveries =     (
        "0x7bf12930 <x-coredata://E8AAE873-94B7-42F4-A39A-3A8D7C567747/DriverRouteDelivery/p24>",
        "0x7c663b80 <x-coredata://E8AAE873-94B7-42F4-A39A-3A8D7C567747/DriverRouteDelivery/p14>",
        "0x7c663f60 <x-coredata://E8AAE873-94B7-42F4-A39A-3A8D7C567747/DriverRouteDelivery/p21>"
    );
    routes =     (
        "0x7f5df860 <x-coredata://E8AAE873-94B7-42F4-A39A-3A8D7C567747/Route/p33>",
        "0x7bf131f0 <x-coredata://E8AAE873-94B7-42F4-A39A-3A8D7C567747/Route/p22>",
        "0x7bf12940 <x-coredata://E8AAE873-94B7-42F4-A39A-3A8D7C567747/Route/p29>"
    );
    startAt = "2015-06-22 15:35:32 +0000";
    synced = "2015-06-22 15:56:29 +0000";
})
```

and

```
<DriverRouteDelivery: 0x81323d70> (entity: DriverRouteDelivery; id: 0x7bf12930 <x-coredata://E8AAE873-94B7-42F4-A39A-3A8D7C567747/DriverRouteDelivery/p24> ; data: {
    delivery = "0x7c143b60 <x-coredata://E8AAE873-94B7-42F4-A39A-3A8D7C567747/Delivery/p15>";
    route = "0x7c0ed070 <x-coredata://E8AAE873-94B7-42F4-A39A-3A8D7C567747/DriverRoute/p8>";
    sortOrder = 1;
})
```

It's pretty obvious that the set `routeDeliveries` contains the object `<x-coredata://E8AAE873-94B7-42F4-A39A-3A8D7C567747/DriverRouteDelivery/p24>"` but if I try e.g. `[routeDeliveries containsObject:routeDelivery]` it occasionally return NO, the printed output above shows it's there.

Both objects are in the same context and the context is used on the correct queue.

**Any one any ideas, what might cause this behaviour?**

Comment: `containsObject` is just looking for the same `id` ... so it matters how you initialize `routeDelivery`

Comment: @stevesliva not quite sure if that makes sense. Shouldn't containsObject use the hash or something like that to compare the objects in the Set? Further that would mean that if I call `removeRouteDeliveriesObject:` I could never do a fetch of the object before and use it as argument of this function or am I miss understanding something?